# How to find the distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $w_t$ be a standard Wiener process. Find a distribution of a random variable $η:=\max_{0≤t≤T}(w_t+Ct)$ as a function of $C∈R$.

I know that if $w_t$ is a standard Wiener process than $w_t+Ct$ is too. But what is the next step I don't know. May be Law of the iterated logarithm?